# How do I display Django Rest Framework Foreign Key in Angular?

Tags: django, angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

DISCLAIMER: This is gonna be a pretty long description of a problem, to which I can't seem to find sources for that could help me. So any piece of information is appreciated!
I might add that I am fairly new to Angular and text script.

I have set up my backend with Django and set up the Rest Framework. These are my models:

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250, blank = True)
    job = models.ForeignKey('Job', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Job(models.Model):

    job_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = False)
    rank = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_name
```

In the backend I have set up different job names (Doctor, Teacher, etc...). So when I create a new Person, I get to choose from one of the different jobs, which have been created prior to this. (This is exactly how I woukd want my frontend to work)

Here are my serializer.py, views.py and urls.py files:

**serializer.py**

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta: 
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'job')

class JobSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta: 
        model = Job
        fields = ('id', 'job_name')
```

**views.py**

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        person = Person.objects.all()
        serializer = PersonSerializer(person, many = True, context = {'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

class JobViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        job = Job.objects.all()
        serializer = JobSerializer(job, many = True, context = {'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('person', views.PersonViewSet)
router.register('job', views.JobViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

The Rest Framework has successfully been integrated and I can now create, read, update and delete (CRUD) my models.

In Angular I have created a person component with a service, which contains very simple functions, to use CRUD on my frontend.

**person.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonService {
  backendURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getPerson():Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.backendURL + '/person/',
    {headers: this.httpHeaders});
  }

  getOnePerson(id):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.backendURL + '/person/' + id + '/', 
    {headers: this.httpHeaders});
  }

  updatePerson(person): Observable<any> {
    const body = { name: person.name, job: person.job, };
    return this.http.put(this.backendURL + '/person/' + person.id + '/', body,
    {headers: this.httpHeaders});
  }

  createPerson(person): Observable<any> {
    const body = { name: person.name, job: person.job, };
    return this.http.post(this.backendURL + '/person/', body,
    {headers: this.httpHeaders});
  }
  
  deletePerson(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(this.backendURL + '/person/' + id + '/',
    {headers: this.httpHeaders});
  }
}
```

And my component ts file:

**person.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonService } from '../../services/person.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-person',
  templateUrl: './person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./person.component.css'],
  providers: [PersonService]
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {

  person_all = [{ name: ''}, ];
  selectedPerson;

  constructor(private api: PersonService) {
    this.getPerson();
    this.selectedPerson = { id:-1, name: '', job: '', }
   }
   getPerson = () => {
     this.api.getPerson().subscribe(
       data => {
         this.person_all = data;
       },
       error => {
         console.log(error);
       }
     )
   }
   personClicked = (person) => {
    this.api.getOnePerson(person.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.selectedPerson = data;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }
  updatePerson = () => {
    this.api.updatePerson(this.selectedPerson).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.getPerson();
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  createPerson = () => {
    this.api.createPerson(this.selectedPerson).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.person_all.push(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  deletePerson = () => {
    this.api.deletePerson(this.selectedPerson.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.getPerson();
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

In HTML I created a very simple view, in where I can see every created Person and some buttons to create, update or delete some.

**person.component.html**

```
<h2>Person List</h2>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let person of person_all">
        <h2 (click)="personClicked(person)">{{person.nachname}}</h2>
    </li>
</ul>

Name <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson.name"/><br> 
Job <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson.job"/><br>


<button *ngIf="selectedPerson.id != -1" (click)="updatePerson()"> PUT   </button>
<button *ngIf="selectedPerson.id == -1" (click)="createPerson()"> CREATE </button>
<button *ngIf="selectedPerson.id != -1" (click)="deletePerson()"> DELETE </button>
```

This is my problem: When I try to create a new Person, I don't see the different job names, which I have set up in the backend. I want to know, how do I get a "list" of jobs to select from, similar to how it works in Django with a Foreign Key?

Thanks for the read and thanks in advance!

Comment: this.person_all.push(data); When you debug this line, do you get the new person as data?

Comment: @Alexander yes I do, But I can only create a new person, if I put the django rest framework url from a job in the field. So instead of just selecting/typing "Doctor" for job, I put this: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/job/1/"